# How could I replicate a product listing like Amazon's?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I was interested about how could I make a product listing like Amazon's  tried but failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make something like this with HTML and CSS - in most cases. Elements in HTML are represented as boxes - so, just draw the boxes out - and then pick out the appropriate elements and write the HTML to define the content (a list) - and then the CSS to suggest how it should behave visually

[image]'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element && https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference are the toolboxes

```css
/* SETUP */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

picture {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


.thing-list {
  border: 5px solid lime;
}

.thing-list .thing {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.thing-list .thing:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.thing-list .image {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.thing-list .info {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.thing-list .info *  {
  border: 5px solid #ff0066;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .thing-list .thing {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .thing-list .info {
    flex-grow: 1; /* yes */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="thing-list">

  <li class="thing">
    
    <picture class="image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/600">
    </picture>
    
    <div class="info">
      <h2 class="title">Thing title</h2>
      
      <p class="description">Thing description</p>
    </div>
    
  </li>


  <li class="thing">
    
    <picture class="image">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/600">
    </picture>
    
    <div class="info">
      <h2 class="title">Thing title</h2>
      
      <p class="description">Thing description</p>
    </div>
    
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: any tips of how could I make the title and price always be to the side of the img?

Comment: I have done all what you said, (from the html side) but I really do not know how to stack them up and make it look like this with the css

Comment: If you make the green line (element) (ul element) `display: flex; flex-direction: column` - you'll make a column. If you make the red line (li element) `display: flex; flex-direction: row` - then that'll take care of that.

Comment: READ THIS: https://dev.to/perpetual_edu/almost-all-of-the-ui-comes-down-to-just-this-24ef